# Помощь в понимании функции с использованием регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Прошу помощи в понимании кода ниже, вопрос там же после строки кода (в комментарии к нему):

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(match):
    degCelsius = float(match.group('celsius'))
    degF = 32.0 + (degCelsius * 9.0 / 5.0 )
    return f"{degF} F"


pattern = r"(?P<celsius>d+)\u00B0C"
text = "Today's temperature is 49 * C"

print(f'Pattern: {pattern}')
print(f'Text before: {text}')

new_text = re.sub(pattern, celsius_to_fahrenheit, text) 
# Каким образом параметр match передается в функцию celsius_to_fahrenheit,
#  если явно этого не происходит?
print(f"Text after: {new_text}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> re.sub = sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
> ```
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
> occurrences of the `pattern` in string by the replacement `repl`.  `repl`
> can be either a string or a callable; if a string, backslash escapes
> in it are processed.  If it is a callable, it's passed the `Match`
> object and must return a replacement string to be used.

Если в качестве второго аргумента передается не строка, а функция, то совпавшая строка будет заменена на результат вызова этой фукнции. В качестве аргумента ей будет передан объект типа `Match`, он содержит все найденные группы и прочую полезную информацию о сопоставлении этой строки с регулярным выражением.